# VS Code, typings - no IntelliSense

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I have a project with the following (shortened) structure.

```
.
├── app
│   ├── app.css
│   ├── app.js
│   └── home
│       ├── home.css
│       ├── home.html
│       └── home.js
├── jsconfig.json
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
├── typings
│   ├── globals
│   │   ├── jquery
│   │   │   ├── index.d.ts
│   │   │   └── typings.json
│   │   └── office-js
│   │       ├── index.d.ts
│   │       └── typings.json
│   └── index.d.ts
└── typings.json
```

As you can see, I have initialized and installed typings for the project.
However VS Code does not recognize the *.d.ts-files for IntelliSense.
So I do not get properly code completion, quick info etc.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

jsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I have read all related blogs and questions on this topic, but do not came across a working solution.

Comment: Since you've found a solution, you should post the solution as an answer to your question and mark it as accepted - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17847/308046.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime (after hours of struggling) I came across my own solution.
Simply set the compiler option **allowJs** to **true** in tsconfig.json and save.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

This is obviously a bug because it´s default is true according to [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).
I´ve posted this issue additionally on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14322).