# VS Code does not recognize the *.d.ts-files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

My project's structure:

```
.
├── node_modules
│   ├── @types
│
├── server
│   ├── server.js
│   ├── server.ts
│
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

The server.ts is identical to the server.js. Only the file extension is different.
Package.json contain such dependencies as express and @types/express.
When I move the cursor to the string

```
const app = express();
```

in the server.js (notice - js!), I get a tip:

```
const app: Express
```

But in the server.ts the tip is:

```
const app: any
```

My tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  }
}
```

AllowJs was added after reading this question:
[VS Code, typings - no IntelliSense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224476/vs-code-typings-no-intellisense) 
It didn't help.
 
How to force the IDE to use the d.ts files in the @types folder?

Comment: can you remove your typeroots? This is also among the default values, check here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: I suggest to add the compiler option `"traceResolution": true` to your `tsconfig.json`, then look at the messages.

Comment: I had an issue where VS Code said it couldn't find type definitions but `tsc` worked just fine. I restarted VS Code and it started working.